# Angular v15 npm run test fails in CI/CD machine with error "Uncaught TypeError: __webpack_require__(...).context is not a function"

Tags: angular, testing, cicd, angular15

After updating Angular from v14 to v15, I saw Angular CLI remove lines from the src/test.ts file. The lines were:

```
declare const require: {
    context(path: string, deep?: boolean, filter?: RegExp): {
        <T>(id: string): T;
        keys(): string[];
    };
};
```

and

```
// Then we find all the tests.
const context = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
// And load the modules.
context.keys().forEach(context);
```

This of course made the "npm run test" command fail locally, because the test files are not explicitly given to Angular. So I added the lines back and everything started to work locally. The CI/CD machine can not run the "npm run test" command anymore. The command prints to the standard output the following:

```
29 11 2022 13:00:59.161:INFO [karma-server]: Karma v6.3.20 server started at http://localhost:9876/
29 11 2022 13:00:59.167:INFO [launcher]: Launching browsers ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox with concurrency unlimited
29 11 2022 13:00:59.172:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser ChromeHeadless
29 11 2022 13:00:59.649:INFO [Chrome Headless ip.ip.ip.ip (Linux x86_64)]: Connected on socket sockedId with id ID
Chrome Headless ip.ip.ip.ip (Linux x86_64): Executed 0 of 0 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)
Chrome Headless ip.ip.ip.ip (Linux x86_64) ERROR
  An error was thrown in afterAll
  Uncaught TypeError: __webpack_require__(...).context is not a function
  TypeError: __webpack_require__(...).context is not a function
      at Object.4289 (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/src/test.ts:25:25)
      at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap:19:1)
      at __webpack_exec__ (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/main.js:67164:48)
      at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/main.js:67165:54
      at Function.__webpack_require__.O (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/webpack/runtime/chunk loaded:23:1)
      at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/main.js:67166:56
      at webpackJsonpCallback (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/webpack/runtime/jsonp chunk loading:34:1)
```

No clue what's creating this issue. Cache has been cleared on the CI/CD machine.

Tried adding back the lines that angular update from v14->v15 removed and it fixed the problem locally, not on the CI/CD machine.

**EDIT/UPDATE:**
"ng test" now randomly stopped working on my local machine as well. I fiddled around with the test.ts, angular.json and karma.conf.js conf files and removed the lines again that Angular CLI had previously removed from test.ts. The tests were able to be ran locally now. The tests were also able to run on the CI/CD machine now. Weird...

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74886791/16266725). The accepted answer helped me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Testing - After Angular 15 Update throws Error "\_\_webpack\_require\_\_(...).context is not a function"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74823633/testing-after-angular-15-update-throws-error-webpack-require-context)

Comment: Thats exactly the same question that I mentioned :-)

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and only fixed it after comparing my code to their startup project: https://angular.io/generated/live-examples/testing/stackblitz.html.

In Angular 15, they removed tests.ts altogether. You should delete the file and then edit your Angular.json to not refer to it (just delete the "main": "src/test.ts" option).

Comment: This does fix the error, but none of the tests now pass. The test.ts file had zone.js imports and initiated the testing. Now that tests.ts is gone fakeAsync tests fail due to zone.js not being imported and Angular Material components are not recognized in the tests anymore, which also creates errors. Zone.js can be imported via the angular.json file under test.options.polyfills, but this leaves the problem with Angular Material.

Comment: Maybe you forgot to also include zone.js/testing? If you look at the sample project they have: "polyfills": ["zone.js", "zone.js/testing"] under test.options.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74886791/16266725). The answer helped me, I found nothing about these changes made to the test.ts file!