# Testing - After Angular 15 Update throws Error "__webpack_require__(...).context is not a function"

Tags: angular, testing, karma-jasmine, angular15

After the Update from Angular 14 to 15 my Tests won't run anymore. When I run ng test I get the following Error:

```
An error was thrown in afterAll
  Uncaught TypeError: __webpack_require__(...).context is not a function
  TypeError: __webpack_require__(...).context is not a function
      at Module.4289 (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/src/test.ts:22:30)
      at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap:19:1)
      at __webpack_exec__ (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/main.js:180646:48)
      at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/main.js:180647:54
      at Function.__webpack_require__.O
```

---

My test.ts file looks like this and is set in the angular.json as "main".

```
// This file is required by karma.conf.js and loads recursively all the .spec and framework files

import "zone.js/testing";

import { getTestBed } from "@angular/core/testing";
import { BrowserDynamicTestingModule, platformBrowserDynamicTesting } from "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing";

declare const require: any;

// First, initialize the Angular testing environment.
getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(BrowserDynamicTestingModule, platformBrowserDynamicTesting());
// Then we find all the tests.
const context: any = require.context("./", true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
// And load the modules.
context.keys().map(context);
```

---

I tried removing the file but this does not seem to solve the Problem. After that I got Error in Third Party Libraries (dhtmlx gantt) that don't come up when running the app with ng build. ng build runs fine, the app works - only the tests are failing.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The upgrade tool removes the context lines because they are not necessary anymore, try this:

```
    // This file is required by karma.conf.js and loads recursively all the .spec and framework files

import "zone.js/testing";

import { getTestBed } from "@angular/core/testing";
import { BrowserDynamicTestingModule, platformBrowserDynamicTesting } from "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing";

// First, initialize the Angular testing environment.
getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(BrowserDynamicTestingModule, platformBrowserDynamicTesting());
```

Comment: yes, thank you, I have an upgraded v15 app and i replaced the test.ts file with this and now it all works!  High five

Comment: Thank you very much - this is was a massive help

Comment: Bro! hats off to you. 
I was struggling to make it work. And this worked like a charm!! Lets have some beer someday.

Comment: I can confirm that this answer works. I have replaced the contents of test.ts with this, which did the trick. God bless you!

Comment: this is for src/test.ts file

Comment: Thank you so much! I was struggling on this issue from long time, you saved me.

Answer (score 13):

Try to run

```
ng update @angular/cli --from 14 --to 15 --migrate-only
```

which should update **test.ts** file and remove require.context lines below

```
const context = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
context.keys().forEach(context);
```

after that you can execute testing for a single or multiple files using **--include** param

```
ng test --include=**/some-file.spec.ts
```

Comment: Where can I find information like that?
I wonder why there is no information about those things in the official angular update guide.