# What could be causing 'ng test' to not execute any unit tests in my Angular project?

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

```
ng test
```

is not executing any test cases in spec files.

In my projeect, when I run

```
ng test
```

it is giving me the result as below:

```
seChrome 113.0.0.0 (Windows 10): Executed 0 of 0 SUCCESS (0.002 secs / 0 secs)
TOTAL: 0 SUCCESS
```

Test cases are written in the component level (spec files).
The ng test command is not executing them.

I have looked into angular.json, tsconfig.spec.json, tsconfig.json and everything looks fine to me.
I tried some things like downgradiung the target to ES2015 from ES 2022 but nothing seems to work.

Please suggest what might be the issue here.
Thank you.

karma.conf.js

```
// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client: {
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, '../coverage'),
      reports: ['html', 'lcovonly'],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml', 'jasmine'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I [came across this link](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/24389) and tried the solution that worked for **mylifeandcode**.

I then started encountering a different error as below:
[image]

Then I searched for the above error and [came across this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74823633/testing-after-angular-15-update-throws-error-webpack-require-context) and the accepted answer here worked for me.

Replaced the contents of test.ts file with below worked:

```
// This file is required by karma.conf.js and loads recursively all the .spec and framework files

import "zone.js/testing";

import { getTestBed } from "@angular/core/testing";
import { BrowserDynamicTestingModule, platformBrowserDynamicTesting } from "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing";

// First, initialize the Angular testing environment.
getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(BrowserDynamicTestingModule, platformBrowserDynamicTesting());
```